# How to proxy specific repo with git protocol in .git/config file?

Tags: git

I know I can set a global proxy like this:

```
git config --global http.proxy  http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy https://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

By I don't wanna to set it global, and I use `git` protocol to pull/push. I tried to do the following setting in `.git/config` file:

```
[git]
    proxy = yixia.dev
```

But it doesn't work.

I use a workaround by running `git config --global url."git@yixia.dev".insteadOf git@github.com`, it works, but when I change `--global` to `--local`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the config at your local repo level using no flag [without --global] or add --local instead.

To remove the current proxy you have already set up:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Since the proxy has nothing to do with git you might need to not set the proxy at all and instead set the OS proxy instead.

Open google chrome  >settings > proxy and set it there (no matter what OS you are on).

Comment: How to proxy `git` protocol?

Comment: What you did is the right way but sometimes you cant get get to work beyond proxy without setting the OS to use proxy. its long to explain but it depends on your clone protocol that you used. there are 6 optional protocols

Comment: I don't very understand the reason that `cant get to work beyond proxy without setting the OS to use proxy`. I use a workaround, see my update. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on your clone protocol

Comment: I use https/http/git.

Comment: Are you beyond firewall?

Comment: Nope I closed it. It's a little bit strange.

Comment: really strange, if you are not beyond firewall setting up proxy should work. Once you set it you should have the [http] section in your config files.

Still i will try to help as much as i can.